# Applying Styles in PDF GridView using itextsharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, pdf-generation, itext

I'm trying to print a panel which contains data like labels and GridView to a PDF using **itextsharp** in my webpage. But if i'm not able to apply the styles to the GridView.

Can you help me??

I'm using both css and html styles to style my GridView.

```
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline;filename=" + filename + ".pdf");
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
pnl_print.RenderControl(hw);

StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 100f, 0f);
HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
pdfDoc.Open();
htmlparser.Parse(sr);
pdfDoc.Close();
Response.Write(pdfDoc);
Response.End();

sr.Close();
hw.Close();
sw.Close();
```

How can I add styles to Gridview in Panel??

Panel ID is pnl_print

GridView ID is gv1

Can you Help me out ??

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it possible to add an extranal css to the pdf with itextsharp, but you can always create a css with a functions frovided by itextsharp using something like this,  rewriting the style in the itextsharp css class.

```
StyleSheet styles = new StyleSheet();
styles.LoadTagStyle("p", "size", "10pt");
styles.LoadTagStyle("p", "color", "#0000ff");
```

Comment: I'm making a panel in to the PDF and the Panel contains GridView I'm referencing only the panel in itextsharp. So the GridView is the Sub element of panel. How to add styles to the GridView in Panel

Comment: yes but you are adding the panel to pdf with itextsharp,, right?? you need to use example like above to add style to any element that you create with itextsharp

Comment: Can you explain in detail, I'm novice in this topic & I've added my code.