# asp.net application - View uploaded file instead of downloading

Tags: asp.net, file, file-io

We have a asp.net application which allows users to upload files.

After the file has been uploaded, users get an option to download the file to view it.

We wish to also give a preview link. Clicking this link should open the file in the browser pop-up (Chrome and Firefox).

Users typically upload pdf, common image formats and word documents.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thank You
Yash

Comment: Do you mean you wish the user to view the document inside the browser instead of downloading it? That is not possible for Word-documents. Only images, PDF and plain text.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Opening a PDF in browser instead of downloading it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12086321/opening-a-pdf-in-browser-instead-of-downloading-it)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirement, I think you can use Google Docs Viewer.

Sample can be found over [here](https://docs.google.com/viewer)

For more information this is the [link](https://drive.googleblog.com/2009/09/view-online-files-using-google-docs.html) of google blog explaining Google Docs Viewer.