# view (VIEW ONLINE) file instead of download from gridview using Eval in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I want to make a button (VIEW ONLINE) so that people can view PDF online in new tab when they click on it and those who want to download they can easily download. i have developed download but failed to make VIEW ONLINE .

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/urg_list/"));
        List<ListItem> files = new List<ListItem>();
        foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
        {
            files.Add(new ListItem(Path.GetFileName(filePath), filePath));
        }
        GridView1.DataSource = files;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
protected void DownloadFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string filePath = (sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument;
    Response.ContentType = ContentType;
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Path.GetFileName(filePath));
    Response.WriteFile(filePath);
    Response.End();
}
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: There are two approaches here. You can rely on the browser to recognise that it's a pdf file or you can embed a pdf reader in your webpage and then display the pdf. If you don't want o be left at the whims of the browser I'd advise you try the second method.

Comment: i want code that when i click on view online it auto opens the file in new tab

Comment: I think @chidambaram's answer should do the trick if you want it to open in browser.

Answer (score 1):

For that you have to set the content disposition as inline instead of attachment.
Try the below, this may work.

```
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline;filename=" + filename + ".pdf");
```

or

```
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + Path.GetFileName(filePath));
```

Comment: my file doesn't open in pdf format and not in new tab.

Comment: did you get any error? did you try in different browser?

Comment: no i didn't get error. but my file doesn't open's in new tab and in pdf format

Comment: Try this bro, may be some other lines are cusing it not to display it in browser. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12086321/opening-a-pdf-in-browser-instead-of-downloading-it